# Read multiple json in python

Tags: python, json, pandas

I need to convert an unconventional json file into a dataframe. I can loop through and do it. However, I was just wondering if there are other efficient ways of doing the same thing. The json I have is of the following format

```
{"K1": "V11", "K2": "V12", "K3": "V13"}
{"K1": "V21", "K2": "V22", "K3": "V23"}
{"K1": "V31", "K2": "V32", "K3": "V33"}
```

I want to read it as a dataframe as follows

```
K1   K2   K3
V11  V12  V13
V21  V22  V23
V31  V32  V33
```

Are there any streaming Json packages or any easy approach to do this. Any help would be great.

Comment: That is more like a dict to me , not json

Comment: Absolutely right @WeNYoBen. But this is the way the source data is structured which is actually a log file. Can you please help with this? What would be the best way to create a dataframe from such a file?  I can also save the source file as .txt  if required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting from Pandas 0.19, read_json has native support for [JSON in multiple lines](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/user_guide/io.html#io-json-reader)

```
pd.read_json(jsonfile, lines=True)
```

where jsonfile is:

```
{"K1": "V11", "K2": "V12", "K3": "V13"}
{"K1": "V21", "K2": "V22", "K3": "V23"}
{"K1": "V31", "K2": "V32", "K3": "V33"}
```

from doc,

> jsonfile : a VALID JSON string or file handle / StringIO. The
> string could be a URL. Valid URL schemes include http, ftp, S3, and
> file. For file URLs, a host is expected. For instance, a local file could be file ://localhost/path/to/table.json

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I put your data in a file named jsonlike.txt

```py
import pandas

the_df = pandas.read_json("jsonlike.txt", "columns", lines=True)
print(the_df)

output:
    K1   K2   K3
0  V11  V12  V13
1  V21  V22  V23
2  V31  V32  V33
3  V11  V12  V13
4  V21  V22  V23
5  V31  V32  V33
6  V11  V12  V13
7  V21  V22  V23
8  V31  V32  V33
```